# Fill Curve flattens the curve

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I am trying to fill a 3D curve but every time I use the *Fill Curve* node it gets flattened.

[image]

Maybe I am missing something?

Is it possible to convert this curve to a mesh and fill it? Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The node `Fill Curve` always creates a planar mesh on the X/Y axis.

The [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/fill_curve.html) states:

> *The mesh is only generated flat with a local Z of 0.*

Unfortunately, all the attributes that the points originally had are also lost in the process. The reason for this is that the topology is recreated during this process, and the original values are not automatically transferred.

This is technically also not 100% possible, because the node `Fill Curve` creates for example with several curves which are converted at the same time, also new intersection points with the production of the mesh.

---

### Blender 3.1 -3.3

However, not only to answer the question asked, but also to solve your specific problem, here you will find the answer:

[image]

You would simply have to, after applying the node `Fill Curve`, transfer the positions of the original curve.

Then you can triangulate the mesh and so on.

### Blender 3.4+

If you are using Blender 3.4 or higher, just replace the node `Transfer Attribute` with `Sample Index`:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! That is perfect, thank you

Comment: @Ebi You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can use *convex hull* to get shape out of it:

[image]

Normals pointed down may be removed:

[image]

Comment: i don't get it!? if i use convex hull on a closed curve, i get this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjlNi.png

Comment: yep of course it is not flat.

Comment: but i think he wants a curved plane, not filled object....

Comment: We don't know for sure. Technically it is one of the answers. I suppose this site is not only for asking, but also for googlers.

Comment: that's for sure ;)

Comment: It is an interesting take, but I do want a curved plane. Closest is @Chris answer, but using two curves makes it a bit fiddly

Comment: would it be possible to remove the other parts of the mesh and leave only the top planes?

Comment: well, kind of. I've updated the answer.

Comment: now you deserve the +1 from me too ;) love it

Answer (score 2):

you can connect 2 curves like this (if you want a "curved plane" and not "filled object"):

[image]

[image]