# Geometry nodes - Sample Index vs Store Named Attribute

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to restore position values of a curve after it was flattened by the set Fill Curve based on [Fill Curve flattens the curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270275/fill-curve-flattens-the-curve) , however in 3.4.1 where attribute is no more, hence my initial attempt used a Named attribute and failed miserably as all the values were zet to zero:
[image]

I tried using a capture attribute, but as the documentation mentiones it is doign the same as the Named Attribute, so the result was the same, bunch of points at zero.
I also tried the Sample Index and to my surprise it seems to be doing what I needed, however I don't understand why:
[image]

I went through the docs for both nodes but couldn't figure out why it behaves this way; I'd expect the Named Attribute node manage to handle the type change from curve to mesh.
Could someone explain the difference between the Store Named Attribute/Named attribute pair versus using a Sample Index node that causes this behaviour?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Unfortunately, the `Fill Curve` node discards all the attributes previously assigned to the curve because it recreates the curve and creates a new mesh. The only way to restore them is to transfer the attributes from the original curve using the positions (with `Sample Nearest` and `Sample Index`, or `Transfer Attribute` if you are using version 3.3 or below).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I've been reading your answers on other posts learning a lot from them!